# r llply lapply usage without losing dataframes names

Tags: r, plyr, lapply, names

**Overall situation**:

The interface of my measuring devices couldn’t save any further information but the name of the csv it generates during measuring its values.  So I used a systematic set of abbreviations to account for changing parameters, such as concentrations, enzymes, feed stocks, buffers etc., That combined formed the title of my csv files which form the names of the data.frames , where I am now trying to read out the names, to combine them with the rest of the data, to form tables that I can use to do regressions.

**The Issue:**

I just noticed that I lose the names of my `data.frames` inside the list,
I could rename them after each call of lapply, but this doesn't seam to be a proper solution.

I found suggestion to use the `llply`, but I can't teach it to keep names either.

```
# loads plyr package
library(plyr)

# generates a showcase list of dataframes, 
data <- list(data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,3)),data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,3)),data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,3)),data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,3)))

# assigns names to dataframe
names(data) <- list("one","two", "tree", "four")
```

usses the dataframes name to pass “o” to a column, this part works fine,
But after running it the names are lost

```
data <- lapply(X = seq_along(data), 
  FUN = function(i){    
  x <- data[[i]]
  if (gsub("([(a-z)]).*","\\1", names(data)[i]) == "o") {x$enz <- "o"}
  return(x)}, 
  USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

Same thing with `llply`, operates as expected but doesn’t keep the name either although I thought I could solve that particular problem (quote: “`llply` is equivalent to lapply except that it will preserve labels and can display a progress bar.”)

```
data <- llply(seq_along(data), function(i){    
                 x <- data[[i]]
                 if (gsub("([(a-z)]).*","\\1", names(data)[i]) == "o") {x$enz <- "o"}
                 return(x)})
```

I would very much appreciate a hint how to solve this with out something like

`name(data) <- list.with.the.names`

after each llply ore lapply call.

Comment: If "most of the information is stored in the data.frames names" you apparently have [untidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). You should rectify this and continue from there.

Comment: Interesting article, I but unfortunately my data structure was the least of my concerns during the time I had in the lab to build my experimental setup, so I have to clean up my data now and use what I got now.Please see edited “overall situation”

Comment: Well, add this data as columns to the data.frames (and possibly take this opportunity to parse it, so you have the actual values of interest and not only your code). Nobody forces you to keep it in the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
for (i in seq_along(data)) data[[i]]$name <- names(data)[i]

do.call(rbind, data)
#       c.1..2. c.3..3. name
#one.1        1       3  one
#one.2        2       3  one
#two.1        1       3  two
#two.2        2       3  two
#tree.1       1       3 tree
#tree.2       2       3 tree
#four.1       1       3 four
#four.2       2       3 four
```

And continue from there.